# Mac OSX pip3 issue via brew

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I'm encountering the following issue when I try to launch pip3 after installing python3 via brew.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==6.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-15.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 552, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-15.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2672, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-15.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2345, in load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-15.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2351, in resolve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/download.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .models import Request, Response, PreparedRequest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.fields import RequestField
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .ssl_ import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 12, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 97, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'
```

No problems when I try to launch pip (through Python 2.7.10). I think it's related to the ssl, and I tried to reinstall openssl through brew, and then reinstall python3, but without luck.

I'm also able to correctly launch the python3 shell (python3 command works fine).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to find a solution: the problem was that the openSSL library located in the /usr/bin directory wasn't pointing to the openSSL brew installation.

It was only necessary to execute the following commands sequence:

```
brew reinstall openssl #just in case
brew link --force openssl
brew reinstall python3
```

Executing pip3 should now works.